# How to integrate GigyaNss in my Xcode project?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, authentication, gigya

I'm trying to integrate Gigya within my Xcode project but the official [documentation](https://sap.github.io/gigya-nSS/) lacks for details. First, I don't understand how I should load my schema. I have created a json file and added it to my project. How am I suppose to call the following line of code in AppDelegate?

```
GigyaNss.shared.register(scheme: <YOUR_SCHEME>.self)
```

After the schema is loaded into GigyaNss, should I create a storyboard and a view controller and from there (maybe in `viewDidLoad`) call the function to upload the schema I want?

```
GigyaNss.shared
   .load(screenSetId: "DEFAULT")
   .lang(name: "en")
   .initialRoute(name: "login")
   .events(UserHost.self) { result in
      switch result {
      case .success(let screenId, let action, let account):
        // success
      case .error(let screenId, let error):
       // error
      case .canceled:
        // canceled
     }
   }
   .show(viewController: self)
```

Comment: There is plenty examples inside the folders in this example project. 

https://github.com/SAP/gigya-swift-sdk/tree/e56d7fc20fff3afb65553361d69882c1b978de2d/GigyaE2ETestsApp/GigyaE2ETestsApp

Comment: Thanks I totally missed it and I found no reference to this project in the documentation on SAP.